# PyCharm Run Configuration does not stay

Tags: module, path, configuration, pycharm

I am trying to change PyCharm Run Configuration of *.py file from Script Path to Module Name. It allows me apply changes fine, but when I come back it is still Script Path. I am using PyCharm 2021.2.3 Community Edition.

Comment: Are you givine a unique name to the run configuration? Are you saving the run configuration? Is the module name correct? (relative to known source root)

Comment: Yes, the name is unique, and it allows to apply changes

Comment: Might be an error with IDE settings save. Feel free to either contact PyCharm support at pycharm-support@jetbrains.com or create a ticket in the bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY Attach `idea.log` from **Help | Show Log in ...** - it's the main IDE log file. It should contain the errors if there are any.